# What is the meaning of 'pp' in OSU?

Tags: terminology, osu

I'm just starting to play OSU!
I was watching to know what pros can do in that game, and I just realized they were talking about pp.

What does pp mean? 
What pp is the standard in a game of OSU!?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Osu!, pp stands for **performance points**. There are two main contexts to consider pp in, at the beatmap level and at the account level.

On an individual beatmap, pp is based on the difficulty of the song and one's accuracy score on the song. One can try over and over to improve their performance, but only the best performance on each beatmap will count.

On an account, pp is based on the individual amounts of pp from each song, however, there are diminishing returns to encourage great performances on a few songs over mediocre performances across many songs. One only gets full pp from their very best performance.

To use the currently top player (as of May 23, 2016) as an example, Rafis sits at 12,204pp. Since players are ranked by pp, we know that's more than anyone else. Scrolling down in his profile and opening the "Top Ranks" section, we see that the song granting him the most performance points is Fujijo Seitokai Shikkou-bu - Best FriendS [Insane]. His 98.98% accuracy grants him 715pp. The next song, rated at the song level at 708pp, is granting his account 673pp because the second best song has a weight of 95%. As you go down through the songs, the weights continually decrease, with the total contribution after applying weights eventually summing to the overall account score of 12,204pp.

https://osu.ppy.sh/wiki/Performance_Points